# How to Make HTML Text Fade When Scroll Down

Tags: jquery, html, css

So my issue is I want to create a title that fades when the user scrolls down, like on the following site.

http://demos.themetrust.com/hero/

I found some code here that might work, but I'm also interested in how the Jquery works (i'm new to Jquery), could someone tell me if this code would work in this context and as a bonus could you give a brief overview of *how* it works? Thanks for the trouble.

```
 jQuery(function($) {
    var divs = $('.fade');
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        divs.css({ 
            'margin-top' : -(st/3)+"px", 
            'opacity' : 1 - st/35
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 jQuery(function($) {
    var divs = $('.fade');   //this selects the divs of class 'fade' (multiple)
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {   //this selects the window and attaches to the scroll event.  when scroll occurs, the inline function is called
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();   //gets the vertical position of the current element
        divs.css({ //this changes the css of the divs from before (specifically margin-top and opacity
            'margin-top' : -(st/3)+"px",
            'opacity' : 1 - st/35
        }); 
    });
});
```

Explained inline, hope it helps

Comment: Super awesome! Thanks a lot .